# python numpy convert two diffrent dimension arrays to one tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I got two arrays, the one is(`array A[10][10000]`):

```
 1:   [[   0    0    0 ...,  156  665  621]
 2:    [   0    0    0 ..., -187 -186 -186]
 3:    [   0    0    0 ...,   61  -22  -55]
       ..., 
 8:    [   0    0    0 ...,  540  402  496]
 9:    [   0    0    0 ...,   31   31   33]
10:    [   0    0    0 ..., -525 -504 -492]]
```

length is `10*10000`,type is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` ,and dtype is `int16`

anothor one is(`array B[10]`) : `b=numpy.arange(10)`

```
[   0    1    2 ..., 7 8 9]
```

length is `10`, type is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`, and dtype is `int32`

and I wish to convert this two different dimension arrays to one tuple like this(`tuple C`):

```
(array([[ 0,  0,  0, ...,  156,  665,  621],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ..., -187, -186,    0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,   61,  -22,  -55],
        ..., 
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  540,  402,  496],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ...,   31,   31,   33],
        [ 0,  0,  0, ..., -525, -504, -492]], dtype=int16),
 array( [ 0,  1,  2, ...,    7,    8,    9], dtype=int32))
```

more information about tuple C:

```
print A[0].shape = (10, 10000)
print A[0].dtype.name = int16
print type(A[0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print A[1].shape  = (10,)
print A[1].dtype.name = int32
print type(A[1]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: You can just do `C = (A, B)` right?

Comment: That's amazing.
I was trying to use `tuple(map(tuple,A))`, or `np.vstack`, `np.append`, `np.concatenate`.
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you just want a tuple with the two arrays as elements:

```
C = (A, B)
```